# Unistall Tensorflow with pip3

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pip

I get an import error of tensorflow and I want to uninstall than reinstall it.
By entering this command :

`pip3 uninstall tensorflow` I get this message
**Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed.**

I am on Macos 10.11

Comment: Can you check if `pip3` and the python you are using with tensorflow are from the same environment? Alternatively you can try `python -m pip uninstall tensorflow`.

Comment: @JacquesKvam, sure they are from the same environment. When I enter your command I get the same message

Comment: Alright, there may be faster ways to debug this but what is the tensorflow error you get? What happens when you run this: `python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__file__)"`

Comment: @JacquesKvam, the error is Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import pkgutil; print(pkgutil.get_loader('tensorflow').get_filename())"`?

Comment: @hoefling I run your command with python3 and I get  `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py`

Comment: And what does `pip3 --version` return?

Comment: @hoefling pip 18.0 from `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

Comment: Ok, so if `tensorflow` sources reside in the same site packages that are served by `pip`, but `pip` doesn't see the package (does `pip3 show tensorflow` return something meaningful?), then the package metadata is missing, so you won't be able to properly uninstall it. You can: 1. remove `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow` dir manually or 2. reinstalling ignoring the installed files and hoping that borked files will be overwritten by new installation: `pip3 install --ignore-installed tensorflow`.

Comment: Or you can try finding the lib version from source (usually it's `python -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__))`, but since the import fails, try inspecting the source file in editor). Once you have the version, for example 1.0: `pip3 install --ignore-installed tensorflow==1.0`, now the installation files should be fixed and the package becomes uninstallable again. Now run `pip3 uninstall -y tensorflow` as usual.